# What is the most efficient way to restore "parent - child" relation tree?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a class:

```
class DisplayableUnit
{
    public string ID; //unique ID which is not repeated
    public string ParentID; //ID of parent DisplayableUnit
    [NonSerialized]
    public DisplayableUnit ParentDU; //Instance of parent displayable unit

    //other fields
}
```

Each instance of this class is stored in a **List**.
At some point I serialize each of those instances into a separate file and then load it back.
The **ParentDU** field becomes a **null** of course, and I really don't need to serialize it too.

Now my task is to restore relations between instances, so I look for a most clear and fast way to do it.

What I have is a `**List<DisplayableUnit> LoadedProject.DUnits**` with all deserialized objects.

I wrote some functions to do it, but it's still feels kind of weird and time-consumable to use those.

```
private static List<DisplayableUnit> GetChildDisplayableUnitsFor(DisplayableUnit dunit)
{
    List<DisplayableUnit> ret_list = new List<DisplayableUnit>();

    for (int i = 0; i < LoadedProject.DUnits.Count; i++) //iterate through all deserialized units
        if (string.Compare(LoadedProject.DUnits[i].ParentDUnitID, dunit.ID) == 0) //compare the own ID and parentID of potential child
            ret_list.Add(LoadedProject.DUnits[i]); //add to list if this is child

    return ret_list;
}

public static void RestoreTreeForDU(DisplayableUnit du)
{
    List<DisplayableUnit> childs = GetChildDisplayableUnitsFor(du); //get childs units

    for (int i = 0; i < childs.Count; i++) //iterate through those
    {
        childs[i].ParentDUnit = du; //restore instance link
        RestoreTreeForDU(childs[i]); //make just found child as parent and see if we can restore childs for it.
    }
}

public static List<DisplayableUnit> GetParentDUnits()
{
    List<DisplayableUnit> ret_list = new List<DisplayableUnit>();

    for (int i = 0; i < LoadedProject.DUnits.Count; i++)
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoadedProject.DUnits[i].ParentDUnitID))
            ret_list.Add(LoadedProject.DUnits[i]);

    return ret_list;
}
```

And this is where I start to think what to do next... What I need to do initially to start restore of relations?
Do I need just to iterate through **LoadedProject.DUnits** (all deserialized units) and call RestoreTreeForDU for every unit?

This looks kind of weird since some units there would be already restored and etc.
It's all so confusing :/

Comment: This type shouldn't be a `struct`, it should almost certainly be a `class`.  1) Mutable structs are evil 2) The type doesn't semantically represent a single value 3) You want to logically represent a reference to this object in your current usage of it

Comment: Ok, thank you. Fixed it. Sorry, I don't get the other statemens. I just want to restore the **ParentDU** for each instance basing on string ParentID

Comment: Personally, I'd push all your `DisplayableUnit` into a `Dictionary<string,DisplayableUnit>` using the id as the key. Then it should be easy to iterate through all your DUs and look up the corresponding parent.

Comment: I'd also think about whether or not it's possible for you to add a list of children to your class. It might be easier to start from the root and look up the children (assuming there is only one ultimate parent of the entire collection) rather than doing it from the children back up to the root.

Comment: @MattBurland Either direction is equally easy.  If you take a look at my solution, the only changes to get what you describe is changing `ToDictionary` to `ToLookup` and swapping all uses of `ID` and `ParentID`.

Comment: @MattBurland - The thing with dictionary after deserialization? Also, sadly, but my units should know it's parent, while the parent unit don't care about child ones.

Comment: @Kosmos: Basically I was suggesting what Servy did in a very concise manner.

Comment: @Servy: Actually my thoughts were that starting from the root you could do a breadth first traversal (for example) when you serialize in the first place which could make deserialization easier. For example, you know the first item is your root and the next `n` are it's children. The next `n+m` are the children of the first child of the root, etc.

Comment: @MattBurland 1) That's a lot more work 2) It relies on the ordering of the items 3) It's a very marginal performance difference; the asymptotic complexity of your proposed algorithm is identical to mine.  If you want to do that, by all means, but I wouldn't consider it worth the time/effort.

Comment: @Servy: I don't disagree that it's more complex (but I don't think it's that much more complex - it's undergrad CS level stuff) and any performance gain would be marginal for any reasonably sized data set on any reasonable modern computer. I was just putting it out there as an option.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. This is cool to see. meeeeh I wrote some much of junk-code and someone solwed the task with 4-line code >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a lookup of the ID to the actual object, then you can simply loop through the list and get the value of its parent from that lookup:

```
List<DisplayableUnit> list = new List<DisplayableUnit>();
//todo deserialize into list

var lookup = list.ToDictionary(unit => unit.ID, unit => unit);
foreach (var unit in list)
    unit.ParentDU = lookup[unit.ParentID];
```

Comment: Err and that's all!? Will this restore parent instances for everything? I don't understand what happens there after the first line >_< I don't understand what the usage of undefined **unit** in ToDictionary method.

Comment: @Kosmos Yes that's all, and yes that sets all of the parents for every item.  As I described, it creates a lookup that can map a unit ID to the unit iteself.  It creates a dictionary, loops through all of the items in the list adding a new key of that items ID and adding a value of the reference to that unit, then it loops through all units again looking up its parent and setting the corresponding reference.  `unit` is simply the name given to the parameter of that anonymous method.

Comment: Oh wait, do I need Linq for that? The compiler tells me that: `System.Collections.Generic.List<PageControls.DisplayableUnit>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and no extension method 'ToDictionary' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PageControls.DisplayableUnit>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Kosmos: It's pretty easy to do without Linq as well, but it'll be several lines longer and Linq is worth knowing and loving anyway.

Comment: You probably right. I always find the Linq solutions very small, but still usually code in .net 2.0